# Problem with OpenClover - Clover registry file does not exist, cannot be read or is a directory

Tags: java, clover

Error is

Clover registry file "/Users/tobermei/Downloads/clover-ant-4.4.1/tutorial/build/clover/db/clover.db" does not exist, cannot be read or is a directory.
Please ensure Clover has instrumented your source files.

I have this same problem with a new build I'm creating so I went to the document

https://openclover.org/doc/manual/4.3.0/ant--tutorial-part-0-clover-in-10-minutes.html

ant -f build_quick.xml
Buildfile: /Users/tobermei/Downloads/clover-ant-4.4.1/tutorial/build_quick.xml

with.clover:
[clover-setup] OpenClover Version 4.4.1, built on October 11 2019 (build-1020)
[clover-setup] Clover is enabled with initstring '/Users/tobermei/Downloads/clover-ant-4.4.1/tutorial/build/clover/db/clover.db'

compile:

test:
[junit] Running com.atlassian.samples.money.MoneyBagTest
[junit] Tests run: 22, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.286 sec
[junit] Running com.atlassian.samples.money.MoneyTest
[junit] Tests taking too long? Try Clover's test optimization.
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.073 sec

clover.report:
[clover-html-report] OpenClover Version 4.4.1, built on October 11 2019 (build-1020)
[clover-html-report] Loading coverage database from: '/Users/tobermei/Downloads/clover-ant-4.4.1/tutorial/build/clover/db/clover.db'

BUILD FAILED
/Users/tobermei/Downloads/clover-ant-4.4.1/tutorial/build_quick.xml:74: com.atlassian.clover.registry.NoSuchRegistryException: Clover registry file "/Users/tobermei/Downloads/clover-ant-4.4.1/tutorial/build/clover/db/clover.db" does not exist, cannot be read or is a directory.
Please ensure Clover has instrumented your source files.
You may need to remove existing .class files for this to occur.
at com.atlassian.clover.CloverDatabase.(CloverDatabase.java:87)
at com.atlassian.clover.CloverDatabase.(CloverDatabase.java:65)
at com.atlassian.clover.reporters.CloverReportConfig.getCoverageDatabase(CloverReportConfig.java:325)

java -version
java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)

On macos

sw_vers
ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
BuildVersion: 19H1715

I've had the same problem using OpenClover within a new ant build script, so to prove the problem wasn't with my script, I downloaded the latest OpenClover quick tutorial and built it using their maven script, same error (details above)

Answer (score 0):

I heard back from OpenClover, apparently JDK17 is not supported.  Still having troubles with jdk 1.8/1.9 (supported versions) and will update when I solve that.